# Rolling window fc

Tags: r, window, rolling-computation

Im trying to make a rolling window forecast in R, this is the code:

```
library(lubridate)
library(forecast)


Date = c("2018-01-02", "2018-01-03","2018-01-04","2018-01-05","2018-01-06","2018-01-07","2018-01-08","2018-01-09")
 Sales = c(255, 138, 368, 223, 335, 75, 188, 118)
 ForsøgTS <- cbind.data.frame(Date,Sales)
 str(ForsøgTS)
 ForsøgTS <-  as.data.frame(ForsøgTS)
 ForsøgTS$Date <- as.Date(ForsøgTS$Date)
 
 ForsøgTS <- ts(ForsøgTS$Sales, start = decimal_date(as.Date("2018-01-01")), frequency = 365 )
 
farima <- function(x,h) {
  forecast(auto.arima(x),h=h)
} 
 
 RW <- tsCV(ForsøgTS, farima, window = 3, h = 1 )
```

**bold**

But this does not forecast period t+1 but stops at the last period T. can someone help with the rolling window forecast and maybe also cross validation with rolling window. (but first of all the forecast part).

What I want is to forecast period 9 and 10 (so two periods ahead).

this is the result from running the Code: [output from code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MLV6.png)

Comment: The last result should be always `NA`. If you decrese `window`, you'll also get more results at the beginning.

Comment: What I want is to forecast period 9 and 10 (so two periods ahead).I have added the output from the code in the original post

Comment: The documentation of the function `tsCV` stats that it does forecasts on subsets. This implies to exclude the t+1 time point.  You may have more luck with function explicitly designed for extrapolating data.

Comment: Okay, is there a package in R that does forecast t+1, t+2 .... t+n with a rolling window?

and let me understand it correctly, does that mean that tsCV is only for cross-validation?